# Histogram calculation with Thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

If `i` is a random walk like below (each index is not unique), and there is a device vector `A` filled with zeros.

```
{0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3,  ....}
```

Is it possible that thrust can make `A[i]` auto-increment, after the operation `A` may look like

```
//2 means appears count of 0's
//1 means appears count of 1's
//1 means appears count of 2's
//2 means appears count of 3's
{2, 1, 1, 2}
```

I had tried several cases, but these case only works fine when `A` is a host vector, I guess that because thrust do the parallel, that it previous result can't affect the new one, the result may look like
    //only count once no matter the index appear how many times 
    {1, 1, 1, 1}

Could thrust achieve my goal with device vector A and a random walk index vector?

Comment: thrust::sort then thrust::reduce_by_key

Comment: I tried sort but the performance is not good enough, so now I use "host vector+histogram" method to achieve my goal. The execution time of new method(contain device<-->host overhead) is shorter than sort version. I'm interesting for a better resolution, and asking here.

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-histogram

Comment: do you need to use thrust?

Comment: Using thrust or cuda kernel code are OK! But I'm still interest to know how fast Thrust can achieve when use device_vector?

Answer (score 3):

If you are seeking histogram calculations by Thrust, then you may wish to note that there is a [Thrust documentation example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/histogram.cu) providing two different algorithms:

1. *Dense histogram*, using `sort` to sort the array, then using `upper_bound` to determine a comulative histogram and finally using `adjacent_difference` to calculating the histogram;
2. *Sparse histogram*, using `sort` to sort the array and then `reduce_by_key`, as mentioned by @Eric in his comment.

From this two threads

- [histogram or count_by_key](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thrust-users/SARplGR98Hg);
- [How to obtain a histogram from a sorted sequence](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thrust-users/rqeCeIz1aGo).

I would say that the above are the only two methods to achieve an histogram using Thrust. I have timed both the approaches on a Kepler K20c card and these have been the timing:

- `N=1024*16`; `# bins` = `16*16`; Dense = `2.0ms`; Sparse = `2.4ms`;
- `N=1024*128`; `# bins` = `16*128`; Dense = `3.4ms`; Sparse = `3.1ms`;

On accounting for the fact that the timing does depend on the input array, I would say that the results do not appear to be dramatically different.

It should be noticed that the CUDA samples provide a histogram calculation example, but it is optimized for `64` or `256` bins, so it is not homogeneous to the above mentioned Thrust codes.